# Freshbooks OAuth issue

Tags: oauth

Very quick question for FreshBooks OAuth. When requesting a Request Token you need to provide (among others) the `oauth_signature` method.

Is the signature the consumer key and the consumer secret separated by an ampersand? e.g.

```
_consumer_key_%26_consumer_secret_
```

where `_consumer_key_` is the consumer key. `_consumer_secret_` is the consumer secret and `%26` is a url encoded ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is I was using the request headers instead of the Authorization header.